# Display formatted Date as String for UITextfield

Tags: ios, date, swift, parse-platform, nsdateformatter

I have a date stored in a PFObject on the Parse serves which I'd like to display to the user in a text field. I want the format to be of the style: "Jan 1, 2014" How would I do this after downloading the object? I am using Swift.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you extract the date from the PFObject, you can do something like the below code:

```
var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter();
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMM d, YYYY"
var dateString = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(date)
```